# Swipe to delete from database with password protection alert dialog box

Tags: java, android

I'm doing a Note secure project, and I have set swipe to delete from a database. Also I have set password to delete it. My problem is while swiping the Card View, it shows an alert dialog box. When user selects cancel it, shows Background view  not foreground View .but it structure in background view

Here is my code

```
 @Override
    public void onSwiped(final RecyclerView.ViewHolder viewHolder, int direction, final int position) {
        if (viewHolder instanceof NoteAdapter.MyViewHolder) {
            // get the removed item name to display it in snack bar
            String tittle = notesList.get(viewHolder.getAdapterPosition()).getTittle();

            // backup of removed item for undo purpose
            final Note  note   = notesList.get(viewHolder.getAdapterPosition());
            final int deletedIndex = viewHolder.getAdapterPosition();

            // remove the item from recycler view
            if (notesList.get(position).getLockstatus() == 0)
            {
                mAdapter.removeItem(viewHolder.getAdapterPosition());
            }else{
                final AlertDialog.Builder dBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
                LayoutInflater inflaterd = this.getLayoutInflater();
                View viewd = inflaterd.inflate(R.layout.enter_password, null, false);
                final EditText text3 = (EditText) viewd.findViewById(R.id.edpass);


                dBuilder.setPositiveButton("ok", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {

                        String pass = text3.getText().toString();
                        String unlock = notesList.get(position).getPassword();

                        if (pass.equalsIgnoreCase(unlock))
                        {
                            mAdapter.removeItem(viewHolder.getAdapterPosition());

                            StyleableToast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"Delete successfully...",R.style.exampleToast).show();

                        }else {
                            StyleableToast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"Password does not match...",R.style.exampleToast).show();
                        }
                    }
                });
                dBuilder.setNegativeButton("cancel",null);
                dBuilder.setCancelable(false);
                dBuilder.setView(viewd);
                dBuilder.create();
                dBuilder.show();
            }


            // showing snack bar with Undo option


        }
    }
```

this is custom adapter for swipe

```
import android.graphics.Canvas;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.support.v7.widget.helper.ItemTouchHelper;
import android.view.View;




public class RecyclerItemTouchHelper extends ItemTouchHelper.SimpleCallback {
    private RecyclerItemTouchHelperListener listener;

    public RecyclerItemTouchHelper(int dragDirs, int swipeDirs, RecyclerItemTouchHelperListener listener) {
        super(dragDirs, swipeDirs);
        this.listener = listener;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onMove(RecyclerView recyclerView, RecyclerView.ViewHolder viewHolder, RecyclerView.ViewHolder target) {
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public void onSelectedChanged(RecyclerView.ViewHolder viewHolder, int actionState) {
        if (viewHolder != null) {
            final View foregroundView = ((NoteAdapter.MyViewHolder) viewHolder).viewForeground;

            getDefaultUIUtil().onSelected(foregroundView);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onChildDrawOver(Canvas c, RecyclerView recyclerView,
                                RecyclerView.ViewHolder viewHolder, float dX, float dY,
                                int actionState, boolean isCurrentlyActive) {
        final View foregroundView = ((NoteAdapter.MyViewHolder) viewHolder).viewForeground;
        getDefaultUIUtil().onDrawOver(c, recyclerView, foregroundView, dX, dY,
                actionState, isCurrentlyActive);
    }

    @Override
    public void clearView(RecyclerView recyclerView, RecyclerView.ViewHolder viewHolder) {
        final View foregroundView = ((NoteAdapter.MyViewHolder) viewHolder).viewForeground;
        getDefaultUIUtil().clearView(foregroundView);
    }

    @Override
    public void onChildDraw(Canvas c, RecyclerView recyclerView,
                            RecyclerView.ViewHolder viewHolder, float dX, float dY,
                            int actionState, boolean isCurrentlyActive) {
        final View foregroundView = ((NoteAdapter.MyViewHolder) viewHolder).viewForeground;

        getDefaultUIUtil().onDraw(c, recyclerView, foregroundView, dX, dY,
                actionState, isCurrentlyActive);
    }

    @Override
    public void onSwiped(RecyclerView.ViewHolder viewHolder, int direction) {
        listener.onSwiped(viewHolder, direction, viewHolder.getAdapterPosition());
    }

    @Override
    public int convertToAbsoluteDirection(int flags, int layoutDirection) {
        return super.convertToAbsoluteDirection(flags, layoutDirection);
    }

    public interface RecyclerItemTouchHelperListener {
        void onSwiped(RecyclerView.ViewHolder viewHolder, int direction, int position);
    }
}
```

can anyone help me to solve this? If user cancel then its show as usually

Comment: Your description is not clear. Please elaborate it clearly

Comment: i want to hide background View if user click cancel button on alert dialog box.But it stop on Background View when user select cancel it not showing foreground View